# conditional if on array of string versus constant character

Tags: c++

Using C++ VS 2015.

How do you compare (if) array of string to a constant character without error.

```
string GBD[9] = { "wKQkq--000"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," " };
if (GBD[0][0] = "w")
{ cout << "it is w"; }
```

Error is: C2440 '=': cannot convert from 'const char [2]' to 'char'

I tried "=="

Error is: C2446 '==': no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'

Sorry a bit rusty. I thought since a string is an array of characters, so I assumed two dim array is equal to a character of a one dimension array of string.

Comment: Use `==` to compare, `=` is assignment.

Comment: You need `if (GBD[0][0] == 'w')`

Comment: You can't compare an "array of string to a constant character". You can compare a character only to a character.

Comment: thanks "double quote" fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (GBD[0][0] == 'w')
```

`'w'` is a character, `"w"` is a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

check like this:

```
if (GBD[0][0] == 'w')
{ cout << "it is w"; }
```